# How to achieve the correct closure using Ember.run.debounce

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to use Ember.run.debounce to only trigger the save action on a parent view or controller once when there are many child views triggering save. The problem seems to be closure (anonymous function), but I can't find any examples of the best way to implement debounce within Ember in this context.

Here is a jsbin outlining the issue. Any help or pointers appreciated!

http://jsbin.com/esoNobo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your suspicion is right but the solution is quite easy.

**Your approach:**

```
App.GroupsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'groups_view',
  actions: {
    save: function () {
      Ember.run.debounce(this, function() {
        console.log('groups view save');
        this.get('controller').send('save');
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

});
```

**My solution proposal:** This way you don't have an anonymous function and the Ember run loop is able to do its debounce logic.

```
App.GroupsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'groups_view',
  actions: {
    save: function () {
      Ember.run.debounce(this, this.saveFn, 1000);
    }
  },
  saveFn : function(){
    console.log('groups view save');
    this.get('controller').send('save');
  }

});
```

Comment: Hey mavilein. Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, I thought it might be possible this way too. Unfortunately this does not work either. I think possibly because of the context of 'this', but not 100% sure.

Comment: I see `controller save action` only once in the console. And this is the way it should be, right?

Comment: Ack. Ignore me! It was because I was calling the function inside debounce! this.saveFn() instead of this.saveFn. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an updated working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/axocanI/1/edit?html,js,console,output Thanks for all the help!